# "Operation is insecure" when running WebSQL in Xamarin iOS WebView

Tags: ios, xamarin, uiwebview, xamarin.ios, web-sql

I have a small Xamarin iOS project and in the ViewController I create a UIWebView and have it load local HTML and JavaScript:

```
protected ViewController (IntPtr handle) : base (handle)
{
        var viewBounds = new CGRect (View.Bounds.X, View.Bounds.Y + 1.5, View.Bounds.Width, View.Bounds.Height);
        var containerWebView = new UIWebView (viewBounds);

        View.AddSubview (containerWebView);

        string fileName = "Content/index.html";
        string localHtmlUrl = Path.Combine (NSBundle.MainBundle.BundlePath, fileName);
        containerWebView.ScalesPageToFit = true;

        containerWebView.LoadRequest (new NSUrlRequest(new NSUrl (localHtmlUrl, false)));
}
```

And in the `index.js` file I open up a WebSQL database on a button click:

```
document.getElementById("showDbResult").onclick = function() {
var shortName = 'mydb';
var version = '1.0';
var description = 'Test DB';
var maxSize = 1024 * 1024 * 1024; // in bytes

var db = openDatabase(shortName, version, description, maxSize);

db.transaction(function(trans) {
  createTable(trans);

  insertIntoTable(trans);

  selectFromTableAndUpdateUI(trans);
});
}
```

However, when I run I get the below message in the console:

[image: iOS error]

This worked earlier, I believe before the iOS 10 update came out. Is there a setting in the UIWebView that now needs to be set for this to work?

Comment: This actually seems to be happening randomly when I run the simulator. It just worked and, when I had Safari running to debug something, it quit working. I wonder if something else is causing this to happen.

Comment: Looking at this some more, it may be due to the amount of space it's allocating. The above code is allocating 1GB of data, but if it's changed to 500MB (524288000 in bytes) then it seems to work just fine.